# RedisSearch Module for Redis cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

i am struggling to install RedisSearch module on Rediscluster(Local environment).Using below command but keep on getting error. As i don't know what should be value for OPT1 and OPT2

```
redis-cli --cluster call 127.0.0.1:30001 MODULE LOAD redisearch.so OPT1 OPT2
```

Comment: Don't ask for links. It's not allowed and will get your question closed. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: oops. Let me correct my question.

Comment: Redisearch will not work on a cluster as you expect it to. You need a coordination layer on top of it, and that is a commercial product Redis Labs are providing as part of their enterprise offering.

Answer (score 1):

`redisearch.so OPT1 OPT2`

This command is used to tune the run-time configuration options when loading the module. Opt1 and Opt2 are nothing but the configuration key and value pair.

Example:  `redis-server --loadmodule ./redisearch.so TIMEOUT 100`

Opt1 is TIMEOUT and Opt2 is 100 where the TIMEOUT is the maximum amount of time in milliseconds that a search query is allowed to run.

You can find more of the configuration at [0]

[0] https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/Configuring.html